# Does the Yeoman mongoose generator follow current practices for node.js route creation?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, yeoman-generator

I haven't seen this particular approach before (and I've been digging around a bit in the last few days). I've been looking over a few projects both scaffolded and I presume custom-built to get a sense of what is considered good structure. Since the Yeoman folks consider their generators to be a repository of best practices, I was surprised to see something there I had not seen anywhere else. Is it advanced with significant advantages or interesting with potential downsides? Another SO comment I've read during my search hinted that directly specifying your routes (a la routes.js) had advantages being less "magic-like".

It reads the file system and sets up the routes based on what it finds:

```
// Bootstrap routes/api
var routesPath = path.join(__dirname, 'routes');
fs.readdirSync(routesPath).forEach(function(file) {
  require(routesPath + '/' + file)(app);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it advanced with significant advantages or interesting with potential downsides?

At least one downside would be that it is impossible to compile this with [nexe](https://github.com/crcn/nexe).

But it is an acceptable structure, and I've seen it around before.

That said, generators aren't a good practice themselves. If you have to create something over and over again, you should move it to a separate module, not to write a generator.